# Node.js : Unhandled error on parallel GET requests on a certain time

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, http, get

I'm sending about **100** parallel `GET` requests to an API using [request/request](https://github.com/request/request) module. The problem I have is randomly on about `80th to 100th request`, `node` throws this exception :

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 0.0.0.0:80 //a dummy ip
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:860:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:883:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)
```

Here is my request defaults :

```
var apiRequest = request.defaults({

    url : url, //response is in xml format
    headers : {
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8'
    },
    method : 'GET',
    gzip : true,
    encoding : 'utf8',
    pool: {maxSockets: Infinity},
    forever : true,
    timeout : 120000

});
```

Also I'm requesting using a loop over an array

Comment: About how long does it take to get to the error? A couple of minutes?

Comment: @MattWay yes about 1 or 2 minutes. its variant.

Comment: Try raising your `timeout` quite a bit and see what happens.

Comment: @RaminOmrani doesn't seems like any problem on your side, did you checked whether or not those APIs are responding properly?

Comment: @MattWay again exception thrown

Comment: @iyogeshjoshi yes I can browse the API via browser

Comment: @RaminOmrani Did you tried calling APIs via some REST client?

Comment: With the higher timeout did it fail at approximately the same time? You could try `timeout: 0`

Comment: @MattWay yes almost the same time

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem by requesting the failed urls `on error event` **recursively** till no timeout occurs:

```
function getAPI(url) {
    var apiRequest = request.defaults({

        url : url,
        headers : {
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml'
        },
        method : 'GET',
        gzip : true
    });

    apiRequest(function (error, response, body) {

    }).on('error', function(e){
        getAPI(this.uri.href);//this is important
    }).end();

}
```